# Get the last childnode li from ul where id of the child is not a specifik value

Tags: javascript

I need to get the id of the last li element where the li id is not a specific word

```
var lastChildID = document.getElementById("li_hold").lastChild.id
```

this gives me the last li id but i do not know how to say : get the last li id where id is not for example : hello

Comment: measn you want last `li` of a `ul` which have no id information. right?

Comment: w8, do u want the last li in the document or last li which doesn't have an specific id?

Comment: I want the last li element of the ul where the id is not for example hello. so that means it can be in -10 position from actuall last li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following

```
var list = document.getElementById('list').children;
var lastLI;
var idNotEqual = 'foo3'; // put your not equal ID here
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(list[i].id != idNotEqual){
        lastLI = list[i];
    }
}
console.log(lastLI);
```

Example HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="foo">1</li>
    <li id="foo1">2</li>
    <li id="foo2">3</li>
    <li id="foo3">4</li>
    <li id="foo4">5</li>
    <li id="foo5">6</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

More efficient way:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list').children;
var lastLI;
var idNotEqual = 'foo3';
for(var i = list.length-1; i > 0; i--){
    if(list[i].id != idNotEqual){
        lastLI = list[i];
        break;
    }
}
console.log(lastLI);
```

Comment: or you could run a reverse loop, which would be much more efficient.

Comment: This did the trick thank you very much. I really need to learn this shit

Answer (score 3):

you can get last id of ul li like this

```
var id = $("ul#list li:last-child").attr("id");
if(id!="hello"){
    alert(id);
}

<ul id="list">
    <li id="foo">1</li>
    <li id="foo1">2</li>
    <li id="foo2">3</li>
    <li id="foo3">4</li>
    <li id="foo4">5</li>
    <li id="foo5">6</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry to say. But totally missing the point of the question. Can't believe it still gets so many votes. Keep your eyes open @upvoters

Comment: Well...when i get an idea in my head to do something in a specifik way i need to know: Can i, how to do it...and answers that worked came through

Answer (score 1):

if you use jquery:

```
$('li:last');
```

pure js:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var li = lis[lis.length-1]; // get the last li
```

See if it works (it is untested at the moment)

**UPDATE**
I tested it here is a jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwmAQ/)

Comment: I didn't downvote you but it seems like you've got a typo. It should be "lis.length-1"

Comment: why didnt people check the jsFiddle :/ i updated the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$('li:not(#hello):last')`

Comment: Would really want to see this in plain js

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = document.getElementById('li_hold').querySelectorAll('li:not(#hello)");
var last_li = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

**Edit:** Previously this was returning the first element. As noted, this won't work with some older browsers (http://caniuse.com/queryselector).

Comment: I think this will return the *first* `li` with `id != "hello"`, not the last one.